# Change Status bar color

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I used this code below to make my navigation Controller opacity:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:121.0/255.0 , green:168.0/255.0 , blue: 243.0/255.0, alpha: 0.3)
navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = true
```

the problem with this code is when I use this code, my status bar don't have the same opacity than my navigation bar, why? And how I can solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Click on your Navigation controller in your Storyboard and make sure the Top bar is set to Opaque Navigation bar and the status bar is set to Default. Remove all of the lines of code you have made and do this simple line.

```
self.navigationController!.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 114/255, green: 176/255, blue: 29/255, alpha: 1.0)
```

This will solve your problem. All of those extra lines you have are not necessary for what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Without posting an image my navigation bar don't come transparent, and if it don't come transparent I can not see my background image.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
func setWhiteStatusBarColor() {
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Black
    self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
}

func setBlackStatusBlackColor() {
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Default
    self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
}
```

You can call this functions in your UIViewController class.

Hope it help you

Answer (score 0):

Add this function to your view controller

```
func positionForBar(bar: UIBarPositioning) -> UIBarPosition {
    return UIBarPosition.TopAttached
}
```

This attaches the navigation bar to the status bar and the status bar inherits the opacity properties of the navigation bar.